# Java if-else condition to change output color

Tags: java, css, if-statement

I have this piece of code that I'm stuck with, basically what I'm trying to do is display a different colour of font according to the result. For example if the `returnval > 0` (positive), the output font will be blue, and if the `returnval < 0` (negative), the output font will be red. I think it is simple; however, the thing that I've tried so far doesn't work. Below is the code, hope you guys can guide me.

```
while (rs1.next()) {    
    if (rs1.getString("groupAcc") != null)
        groupAcc = rs1.getString("groupAcc");

    if (rs1.getString("returnvalue") != null)
        returnval = rs1.getDouble("returnvalue");
    if (returnval > 0){ 
        returnval = "<font color=\"#3d9900\"></font>";
    }
    else {
        returnval = "<font color=\"#e64343\"></font>";
    }

    // returnval
    if(rs1.getString("LOGIN") != null)
        login = rs1.getString("LOGIN");
    if (rs1.getString("username")!=null)
        wallet_each_acc = rs1.getString("username");
```

HTML:

```
<td align="right"><span class="box_acc_percent"><%=returnval %>%</span></td>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get a red font all the time, a blue one, or none at all?

Comment: add the language you are using as a tag.

Comment: ypu must have returnval beteen `<font>` and `</font>`

Comment: I'ts not working as it shows: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have defined `'returnval'` as `'double'`.
And you are trying to assign a `string` value to it.

```
returnval = "<font color=\"#3d9900\"></font>";
```

And hence is the Exception.

**Change part of your code as below**:

```
String successStatus = "";
if ( returnval > 0 ){ 
    successStatus = "<font color=\"#3d9900\">" + returnval + " % </font>";
} else {
    successStatus = "<font color=\"#e64343\">" + returnval + " % </font>";
}

// other code should go here
// ...

<td align="right"><span class="box_acc_percent"><%= successStatus %></span></td>
```

And, it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Write some thing between `<font>` and `</font>` Like

```
 if (returnval>0){ 
        returnval = "<font color=\"#3d9900\">Success</font>";
    } else {
        returnval = "<font color=\"#e64343\">Error</font>";
    }
```

Comment: I still get this error Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to double, even though i added success/error

Comment: @railsbox: Upvote on this answer is meaningless. This is does not answer the issue and even a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Questions:
Where is returnval defined. Is it a double?
What is the returnvalue of rs1.getDouble("returnvalue");?

If returnval isn't defined as double, change it.

If the returnvalue of rs1.getDouble("returnvalue") isn't of type double, you will have to convert it. If it is a String (i doubt because it would be awkward) you would have to do

```
Double.parseDouble(rs1.getDouble("returnvalue"), 10);
```

If the type is Double (note the big D meaning it's the Double object instead of the double primitive) you would have to do something like

```
returnvalue = rs1.getDouble("returnvalue").doubleValue();
```

doubleValue() returns the primitive double encapsulated inside of the Double-object and is therefore compareable with == != < > and so on. Objects may only be compared using their .equals() method.

Comment: well. i didn't help. i was blind to see the obvious problem Ravinder pointed out.